# Make a list of months and years in Pandas

Tags: python, list, datetime, pandas, date-range

I am trying to make a date_list that is a range of the months in the last year. It should be formatted `['Oct 2014', 'Nov 2014', 'Dec 2014', 'Jan 2015', 'Feb 2015',... 'Sep 2015']`

Sometimes it works, and sometimes it cuts off the current month. And on the last day of the month it wasn't working so I made this if statement.

```
#If it is the last day of the month, go back a year and add a day to start at beginning of the month
#Otherwise, go back a year, go to the end of the month, and add a day to start at the beginning of the month

if datetime.datetime.now().day == calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]:
    range_min = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)+ pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1, normalize = True)
else:
    range_min = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)+ pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1) + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1, normalize = True)
```

Then I take a slice of my data, which right now goes from 2014-10-01 to 2015-09-02 as expected. 
Then I make the date list! This is the critical bit that I am struggling with.

```
# take slice with required of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]

#Make a date list in order to get the months to plot later on           
date_list = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = range_min, end = datetime.datetime.now(), freq='M'))
date_list = date_list.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%b %Y')).tolist()
```

It may be a problem with my range, which is this:

```
range_min
Out[5]: Timestamp('2014-10-01 00:00:00')

range_max
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 10, 53, 24, 66000)
```

but the first date_list command outputs this:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = range_min, end = datetime.datetime.now(), freq='M'))
Out[8]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2014-10-31 00:00:00, 2014-11-30 00:00:00, 2014-12-31 00:00:00, 2015-01-31 00:00:00, 2015-02-28 00:00:00, 2015-03-31 00:00:00, 2015-04-30 00:00:00, 2015-05-31 00:00:00, 2015-06-30 00:00:00, 2015-07-31 00:00:00, 2015-08-31 00:00:00]
```

Which doesn't include 2015-09 , so my date_list cuts off September. Not sure why this is happening. Also if anyone knows of an easier way to create this list, feel free to include that!

Thanks!

Comment: This list of strings you mention in the beginning is everything you need? Or do you use pandas because you want to work with that list on your dataframes?

Comment: @swenzel Good Question. I later assign date_list to a column in another dataframe. I'm not entirely sure if pandas is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a list of months in the past year without using pandas.

```
date_list=[datetime.date.today()- dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months = x) for x in range(11,-1,-1)]
month_list=[datetime.date.strftime(x,'%b %Y') for x in date_list]
```

If needed you can convert the above list to pandas dateframe with index as months.

```
month_list=pd.DataFrame(index=month_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're problem is the freq='M' is rolling today back to 08/31.  You can look into pd.tseries.offsets.Month and look at using the rollforward method. I've done that in the past.

Another solution is to just build a full list of days, and force that into monthly periods.  This is a bit hackish, but should push you in the right direction:

```
pd.date_range(start = range_min, end = datetime.datetime.now()).to_period('M').unique()
```

Then just take the last 12 from that list (because it returns 13)
I don't think the unique is necessary at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to start from a date and loop through the number of months as follows:

```
months = []
for next_month_date in range(12):
    months.append((pd.to_datetime('2012-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(months=next_month_date)).month_name())
```